Possible to disable HTMX's swapping and just load the page as usual?
I only want to use HTMX to trigger a POST to a different endpoint inside a form (since nested forms aren't allowed). I've got it working, but I don't seem to be able to disable it, and have it just do a dumb full-page reload. It's interfering with my other JS and I don't want to get into fixing it.
I'm looking for a pure front-end solution, no hacking with custom response headers.

An easier approach would be to set the Hx-Refresh header to true on the backend. Since you need frontend solution, maybe you could try hyperscript? Or you only need htmx?

For now I've just dropped back to JS. I thought it'd be easy to progressively adopt, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Add hx-swap="none" to the form that sends the POST and your response won't be swapped into the DOM. https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap/

That just stops it from doing the swap. It doesn't make it do a full page reload instead.
